# Animating contourf plot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a contour plot. The following example is close enough to what I want to achieve (from [this archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg17614.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
f1 = np.sin(X) + np.sin(Y)
f2 = np.cos(X) + np.cos(Y)

plt.figure()
C = plt.contourf(f1)
plt.show()

for coll in C.collections:
    plt.gca().collections.remove(coll)

C = plt.contourf(f2)
plt.draw()
```

However, there seems to be an issue with the `remove` command and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What is the issue? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add

```
plt.pause(0.1)
```

after the `remove` command. This makes matplotlib actually draw the plot up to this point and wait 0.1 seconds so that you can see something happening, before it continues with the next iteration.